# Matlab - Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm working in a project related with vegetation detection and i'm following this tutorial of Matlab to calculate NDVI.

[Finding Vegetation in a Multispectral Image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/finding-vegetation-in-a-multispectral-image.html)

But I'm having an error that i don't know why its happening.
this is the code:

```
% Create a figure with a 1-by-2 aspect ratio
h = figure;
p   = h.Position;
h.Position = [p(1,1:3),p(3)/2];
subplot(1,2,1)
% Create the scatter plot
plot(red, NIR, '+b')
hold on
plot(red(q(:)), NIR(q(:)), 'g+')
ax = gca;
ax.XLim = [0 1];
ax.YLim = [0 1];
axis square
xlabel('red level')
ylabel('NIR level')
title('NIR vs. Red Scatter Plot')
% Display the thresholded NDVI
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(q)
h.Colormap = [0 0 1; 0 1 0];
title('NDVI with Threshold Applied')
```

And this is the error:

??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in ==> teste_nir at 51

p = h.Position;

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what version of Matlab you are using, you may need to use the following instead:

`p = get(h,'Position');`

Comment: I'm Using matlab R2011a

Comment: Yes, so you will need to use the code I wrote instead of `p=h.Position`